# preserve white spaces in mat-table

Tags: angular-material, material-ui, angular-material2

```
<div>
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" >
<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Name </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
</div>
```

I have name "6xxxxxx6xxxxxx". "x" denotes a space. I want to display the name with spaces preserved. The above code removed extra spaces when displayed. The display shows "6x6". How can I preserve the spaces?

Comment: I'm having no problem with white spaces in MatTable with version 5.0.0-rc0.  I'm not sure that "let element" belongs there.  I think you have to use "let row" for all of the rows but I haven't researched this.

Comment: I think this is related to: white-space:pre. But, I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by adding class="pre" using Tachyons.

```
  <div>
   <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" >
      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Name </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>
   <mat-header-row class="pre" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
   <mat-row class="pre" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
    </mat-row>
   </mat-table>
  </div>
```